# POST arrays not showing unchecked Checkboxes

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

Having trouble getting my POST arrays to show all checkbox values from my form.

I have a form set up as follows:

```
<form name='foo' method='post' action=''>
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td class='bla'>Checkbox: <input type='checkbox' name='cBox[]'/></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class='bla'>Checkbox: <input type='checkbox' name='cBox[]'/></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class='bla'>Checkbox: <input type='checkbox' name='cBox[]'/></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

I have a button at the bottom bound to a jquery function that adds 5 more empty rows to the form (hence the arrays for the input name cBox[]).

Now, the problem. Lets say the first checkbox is unchecked, and the last 2 are checked. When I output the values (using PHP print_r for debugging), I will get:

```
Array ( [0] => on [1] => on)
```

For some reason, the array does not contain any value for unchecked checkboxes.

I have seen some solutions where a hidden variable is passed with each checkbox, but can this solution be implemented in my situation (using arrays)?

Comment: sounds simple enough.. I'll give it a go :) thanks

Comment: unfortunately I am still not getting the unchecked values coming through. thanks though

Comment: I realized that my previous comment was motivated by a totally mistaken understanding of your question on my part. I 've added a proper answer below.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That behavior is not surprising, as the browser doesn't submit any value for checkboxes that are unchecked.

If you are in a situation where you need to submit an exact number of elements as an array, why don't you do the same thing you do when there's an `id` of some sort associated with each checkbox? Just include the PHP array key name as part of the `<input>` element's name:

```
  <tr>
                                                       <!-- NOTE [0] --->
      <td class='bla'>Checkbox: <input type='checkbox' name='cBox[0]'/></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class='bla'>Checkbox: <input type='checkbox' name='cBox[1]'/></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class='bla'>Checkbox: <input type='checkbox' name='cBox[2]'/></td>
  </tr>
```

That still leaves you with the problem that unchecked boxes will still not be present in the array. That may or may not be a problem. For one, you may really not care:

```
foreach($incoming as $key => $value) {
    // if the first $key is 1, do you care that you will never see 0?
}
```

Even if you do care, you can easily correct the problem. Two straightforward approaches here. One, just do the hidden input element trick:

```
  <tr>
      <td class='bla'>
        <input type="hidden" name="cBox[0]" value="" />
        Checkbox: <input type='checkbox' name='cBox[0]'/>
      </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class='bla'>
        <input type="hidden" name="cBox[1]" value="" />
        Checkbox: <input type='checkbox' name='cBox[1]'/>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

And two, which I find preferable, fill in the blanks from PHP instead:

```
// assume this is what comes in:
$input = array(
    '1' => 'foo',
    '3' => 'bar',
);

// set defaults: array with keys 0-4 all set to empty string
$defaults = array_fill(0, 5, '');

$input = $input + $defaults;
print_r($input);

// If you also want order, sort:

ksort($input);
print_r($input);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/Pu4fh)**.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I will look into this solution. My only concern is the unique names. I have an unknown number of inputs as they are added with jquery .clone(). Also, your link does not work, can you use a url shortener?

Comment: @SpaghettiMonster: Link fixed (copy paste fail). Even if cloning, you can chain a couple of extra jQuery methods to set the name after the clone is made.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I added a few more lines of jQuery to count the number of existing rows and use this to increment the array positions, and used your code above. Works 100% perfectly! :)

Comment: Good answer, thanks for mentioning the ksort() step at the end, that was necessary in my case!

Answer (score 7):

ONE TRICK is to override the checkbox value, if checked. otherwise its value will be 0.

```
<form>
  <input type='hidden' value='0' name="smth">
  <input type='checkbox' value='1' name="smth">
</form>
```

Comment: While your logic is true this doesn't answer the question because if you have an array than then foreach with key pair will be incorrect

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<input type='checkbox' value="XXX" name='cBox[]'/>
<input type='checkbox' value="YYY" name='cBox[]'/>
<input type='checkbox' value="ZZZ" name='cBox[]'/>
```

Checkboxes work that way. If it is checked, only then the value is posted.

Comment: I tried this, and the result I get is: Array ( [0] => YYY [1] => ZZZ ). Unfortunately I cannot give each input unique values as the can be dynamically added via the jquery function I spoke of.

Comment: Well then replace the YYY, ZZZ with the values you need. Then just check, if $_POST['cBox'] (which is an array) contains needed values.

Answer (score 2):

If you are handling dynamic checkbox array, you can try this:

HTML:

```
<label>
  <input type="hidden" name="cBox[]" value="" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="on" />
</label>
<label>
  <input type="hidden" name="cBox[]" value="" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="on" />
</label>
<!-- extend -->
```

Javascript (jQuery):

```
$(document).on("change", "input.checkbox", function() {

    var value = $(this).is(":checked") ? $(this).val() : null;

    $(this).siblings("input[name='cBox[]']").val(value);    
});
```

Backend result (If only checked the second one):

```
// PHP $_POST['cBox']
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => on
)
```

---

In this implement, the checkboxes are used to controller each hidden input in a group.

For displaying page, You can render each inputs pair back by assigning the value into hidden inputs and marking checkboxes as `checked`.

Comment: Realy help full.. Thank you!!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a value to each checkbox, of 1 or true.

```
<input type='checkbox' value='1' name='cBox[1]'/>
```

that may be why its not sending anything?

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

`request()->merge(['cBox' => request()->input('cBox', [])]);`