# Handling multiple uncheck checkbox

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I can handle multiple checkbox easily but i got problem at unchecked checkbox.

Here the thing.

I 3 checkbox.

```
$resultValue = "BLA BLA";
//where BLA BLA is the query process

<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <?php
        if ($resultValueI['keyboard'] == TRUE)
        {
        ?>
            <input name="checkbox[]" value="keyboard" type="checkbox" class="ace" checked="checked"/>
        <?php
        }
        else
        {
        ?>
            <input name="checkbox[]" value="keyboard" type="checkbox" class="ace" />
        <?php
        }
    ?>
        <span class="lbl"> Keyboard</span>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <?php
        if ($resultValueI['mouse'] == TRUE)
        {
        ?>
            <input name="checkbox[]" value="mouse" type="checkbox" class="ace" checked="checked"/>
        <?php
        }
        else
        {
        ?>
            <input name="checkbox[]" value="mouse" type="checkbox" class="ace" />
        <?php
        }
    ?>
        <span class="lbl"> Mouse</span>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <?php
        if ($resultValueI['battery'] == TRUE)
        {
        ?>
            <input name="checkbox[]" value="battery" type="checkbox" class="ace" checked="checked"/>
        <?php
        }
        else
        {
        ?>
            <input name="checkbox[]" value="battery" type="checkbox" class="ace" />
        <?php
        }
    ?>
        <span class="lbl"> Battery</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Checkbox will **checked** if the info from database is **TRUE**, and **unchecked** when info from database is **FALSE**.

to update the record i need to do the POST method,

```
if (isset($_POST['checkbox']))
{
    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $count = count($checkbox);
}

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    //UPDATE record to TRUE magic happen here           
}
```

When click the submit button, i only get value the CHECKED value, how about the unchecked value, how to update record to FALSE when the checkbox is unchecked?

Comment: If you are not getting any value set it FALSE if(!isset($_POST['field']))

Comment: how to update record to FALSE when the checkbox is unchecked?

Comment: if(!isset($_POST['field'])) {$value_field=FALSE;}

Comment: I'm not quite understand, can you elaborate more?

Comment: I already found the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988325/post-arrays-not-showing-unchecked-checkboxes?rq=1